# Reading sql files from file system and converting them to POJOs using JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jooq

Me have a requirement where SQL stored procs are generated by the system into a folder.
I need to read those sql(Procs) files and covert into POJOs using JOOQ.

Could you please help me how should I go about it.

Thank you.
~Sha

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ does not parse SQL, so the only way for you to go forward is to execute your DDL on an actual database and then use the code generator as indicated in the manual:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/code-generation/

Comment: Thanks a lot Lukas Eder.

I have one more request for you. Me gone through the JOOQ manual , but samples are bits and pieces.

Can you provide a JOOQ complete script for executing a stored procedure. i.e. reading a certain student record from DB for given student ID. A complete stand alone java sample.

Thank you,. ~Sha

Comment: How is JOOQ superior to eBean ORM ? can you elobarate ?

Comment: @user2907154: Please use Stack Overflow to ask one question at a time. It helps future visitors to keep track of what's going on. Also, subjective questions are better suited for other forums, e.g. the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jooq-user)